# glibc not found when enabling compiler optimizations

Tags: cross-compiling, compiler-optimization, glibc, eglibc

I'm cross compiling a shared library ([miniweb](http://miniweb.sourceforge.net/)) for the beaglebone black device. When I compile without optimizations I have no problems. However, if I compile with any optimizations (ie `-O3`) I get the following when trying to run my program:

```
./myprogram: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /usr/lib/libminiweb.so)
```

My first question, why would enabling optimizations suddenly cause my program to be dependent on this library? Is content statically included in the library when optimizations are disabled?

How can I determine the c library version that my cross-compiler is using? I've run the following command `ldd --version` on both systems:

desktop:

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

beaglebone:

```
ldd --version
ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+deb7u1) 2.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Obviously the library I have is outdated, but as you can see my system reports using `eglibc` instead of `glibc`?

How could my cross-compiled library be dependent on `glibc`? Perhaps running `ldd` on my desktop is not an accurate reflection of the libraries used by my cross compiler?

How can I find which c library my cross compiler is using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My first question, why would enabling optimizations suddenly cause my program to be dependent on this library?

Your program *is* dependent on `libc.so.6` with and without optimizations. You can verify this by running `ldd ./myprogram` on the target system.

What's happening is that your program with optimization becomes dependent on *later version* of `libc.so.6` then the one you have installed.

Suppose a header file contains the following:

```
inline int foo() { return bar() + 1; }
```

Further suppose that your program calls `foo`. Without optimizations, `foo` will *not* be inlined, and your program will depend on `foo`.

With optimizations, `foo` *will* be inlined, and your program will no longer depend on `foo`, but will depend on `bar` instead.

If at static link time, you link against a library `lifoobar.so` which provides both `foo` and `bar`, your link will succeed with or without optimizations.

If at dynamic link time (i.e. at runtime) a different version of `libfoobar.so` is used, one that provides `foo` but does not provide `bar`, then unoptimized program will run fine, but optimized program will fail with `bar` not found.

That is what's happening to you, only instead of `bar` you are using *versioned* symbol `some-libc-func@GLIBC_2.15`, and *that* forces your program to depend on version `GLIBC_2.15`, which is what's missing from the target.

> Is content statically included in the library when optimizations are disabled?

No.

> How can I determine the c library version that my cross-compiler is using?

It's using `libc-2.15.so` or later. You should look in your cross-compiler directory.

> desktop:
>   `$ ldd --version`

What you have on your desktop is *completely irrelevant*. What matters is what your cross-compiler is using.

> How could my cross-compiled library be dependent on glibc?

Your cross-compiler provides *its own version* of GLIBC, and your cross-compiled binary depends on *that* GLIBC.

In other words, there are 3 distinct versions of GLIBC here:

1. the one on your desktop (irrelevant)
2. the one your cross-compiler is using to link your binary
3. the one on your target (beaglebone) system.

We know that (2) is at least `GLIBC-2.15` from the error message, and we know that (3) is `GLIBC-2.13` (which is too old).

> How can I find which c library my cross compiler is using?

Look for it under your cross-compiler installation directory.

You could also ask the linker print it for you:

```
echo "int main() { return 0; }" | /path/to/cross-gcc -Wl,-t -xc -
```

Comment: It looks like the library lives here `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6` but how can I know what version it is?

Comment: @dtmland `strings /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6 | grep 'GNU C Library.*version'`.

Comment: Fantastic! `GNU C Library (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu2) stable release version 2.19, by Roland McGrath et al.`

Comment: As a follow up note, It looks like all my compilers use eglibc and not glibc - the original error I received at the top of the post refers to glibc, but I'm guessing the need will be satisfied with eglibc regardless? (I guess I expected the error to refer to eglibc and not glibc?)